# JRuby war dependencies / environment issue

Tags: tomcat, jruby, warbler

I have Sinatra-based application written in Ruby which is packaged using warbler. Resulting file is working fine on my local laptop (Tomcat 7.0.50) and on sandbox host (Tomcat 6.0.35). However, on prod box this war (exactly same file - redeployed and reconfirmed with md5sum) displays following error:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: No such file or directory - file:/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/blah/WEB-INF/lib/gems.jar!/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/../VERSION
 from org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3741:in `read'
 from org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3920:in `read'
```

Prod box have exact same version of JVM and Apache (reconfirmed via currently launched process in Linux).

When I unpack `gems.jar` file I can see that requested `VERSION` file is in place, so it's not a packaging issue.

What else this war is depending on?

What puzzle me a lot is that it's working on different configuration (my laptop) but not working on the same configuration (sandbox & prod).

I'm using JRuby 1.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

try not packing gems into .jar for now, it would better mirror the FS expectations - there are issues from time to time with `__FILE__`, `File.expand_path` etc. usage in a .jar

p.s. Also there might be fixes for this in the latest JRuby 1.7.10 but if not simply disable the **gemjar** feature in Warbler so that the .war does contain the gems as they are (not packed in another jar).